# Presenting UIAlertController causes view inside UITableViewCell to become slightly transparent

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uialertcontroller

I have a part transparent Star Rating view, in which the stars are fully transparent, which is filled with a solid colour view behind to make up the rating. This works fine until I present a UIAlertViewController over the top and causes the image to become slightly transparent revealing the solid colour behind, illustrated in the images below.

[image]

[image]

I have no idea why the alert would cause the image to become transparent, anybody else come across this and have a solution?